# Where is "temp1" located?

Tags: 11.04, temperature

I have all sorts or temperature indicators, one for each core and two for the gpu. but one is just showing "temp1" is there a way to know what temp one is showing?
[image: temp1 selected]

I'm using Indicator Applet Complete 0.4.12 to see the temperatures.

When I ran `sensors-detect` I noticed that there was a virtual device. and "temp1" has the same critical temperatures.

```
$ sudo find /sys -iname "*temp1*"
/sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input
/sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_crit
```

Comment: Do you get something for `sudo find /sys -iname "*temp1*"` or `sudo find /proc -iname "*temp1*"`?

Comment: `sudo find /proc -iname "*temp1*"` Gave nothing.

Comment: Run `sudo sensors-detect`, answer everything with 'y' and post the summary. (Maybe need to install `lm-sensors` first.)

Comment: @htorque this is what i get as "success" or labeled "yes" when typing `sensors-detect` Module i2c-dev loaded successfully. 
Intel digital thermal sensor... Success! 
Probing for `EDID EEPROM'... 
Driver `coretemp': 
* Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Comment: But I still don't know what they control

Answer (score 4):

The labels come from the libsensors config file - `/etc/sensors.conf` - and are determined based on chipset. When you see `temp1` etc. it means there is no label defined yet for that sensor on that chipset. This is probably because it your hardware is new, or your libsensors is old (unlikely with 11.04), or maybe different vendors use the sensor for different things, or other reasons.

I would suggest using the `stress` or other stress-testing command to put load on certain parts of your system in order to determine what the sensor is for, and then add your own label into `sensors.conf`, eg.:

```
chip "lm87-*"
    label temp1 "M/B Temp"
```

Replace the `lm87-*` with your chipset as seen in the output of running `sensors` from a shell.

Comment: nice answer!There may also be a `sensors3.conf`.

Comment: What if "temp1" is located at the motherboard, what should I stress then?

Comment: Good point @Alvar. I'm gonna have to go with process of elimination tho, although it's not a real solution. CPU stress tests would also load the northbridge, which should raise the motherboard temp enough to tell it apart from the case etc. Although if you had two M/B sensors, I cannot think of a surefire way to tell which one is which, without knowing more about the system.

Comment: it may be easier just to look up where temp1 is located, will try that now...

Answer (score -1):

Check out this webupd8 article:

- [Indicator-Sensors Displays CPU/Motherboard Temperature on the Panel Using an AppIndicator [Ubuntu]](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/indicator-sensors-displays-cpu.html)

Currently you can install the PPA version of `indicator-sensors` by running the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors
```

(This integrates the updated information about the official PPA into the commands given in that article.)

The article provides some information about how to configure it after installing:

> Once installed, launch Indicator-Sensors from Dash (it's called
>   "Hardware Sensors Indicator"). **Then you'll need to configure it:**
>   click the appindicator and select "Preferences", then expand the
>   various temperature modules you see in the Preferences dialog and
>   check the box next to the temperature / voltage / fan speed you want
>   to displayed on the panel.